# Detect whether to fetch from psycopg2 cursor or not?

Tags: python, psycopg2

Let's say if I execute the following command.

```
insert into hello (username) values ('me')
```

and I ran like

```
cursor.fetchall()
```

I get the following error

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no results to fetch
```

How can I detect whether to call fetchall() or not without checking the query is "insert" or "select"?

Thanks.

Comment: is the first line looks like `cursor.execute("insert into hello (username) values ('me')")`?

Comment: Chris B is correct, but there's a general concern that an arbitrary query (could be `insert` or `select` or something else) has got this far into the code without knowing what type of query it is. Where is the SQL being entered? Are you protecting against SQL Injection? I strongly suggest that the code should be aware of the type of query being handled and have different code paths for handling `inserts` vs `selects`, ideally using a known set of queries - possibly stored procedures -  and apart from the case where a select query returns no description this question shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Look at this attribute:

```
cur.description
```

After you have executed your query, it will be set to None if no rows were returned, or will contain data otherwise - for example:

```
(Column(name='id', type_code=20, display_size=None, internal_size=8, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None),)
```

Catching exceptions is not ideal because there may be a case where you're overriding a genuine exception.

Comment: Worked for me for a while, but now I am facing a situation when the query returns no rows, but description attribute is not None. Weird.

Comment: `cur.statusmessage` can be used for this purpose. This will return `SELECT 0` or `INSERT 0 1`.

Comment: I really don't understand, my answer below notwithstanding, why the questioner's program isn't distinguishing between update and retrieval queries. I would point out, however, that in the case of a SELECT that retrieves no rows you do still get a valid `description` (making introspection is possible).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it works perfectly! 

The other answers that mention `statusmessage` - *is not correct*.

As en example in case inserting the data into table `INSERT ... VALUES... (1,3,4) RETURNING sid;`.
- The `statusmessage` always returns the `INSERT 0 1` for my sql statement with or without `RETURNING sid` at the end;
- The 'description` property - will return the column list and it's type. in case when INSERT SQL statement without `RETURNING sid` will be equal to `None`;

Answer (score 4):

Check whether cursor.pgresult_ptr is None or not.

```
cursor.execute(sql)
if cursor.pgresult_ptr is not None:
    cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: It won't let me make a small edit, but I believe `in` should be `is`

Comment: you are right of coures, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer using `cur.description` does not solve the problem any more. `cur.statusmessage` can be a solution. This returns `SELECT 0` or `INSERT 0 1`. A simple string operation can then help determine the last query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what turns out to be None is the result of cur.fetchone()
So the way to stop the loop is :

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from rep_usd")
output = cursor.fetchone()
while output is not None:
    print(output)
    output = DBCursor.fetchone()
```

cursor.description will never be None!

Comment: DBCursor is a typo. you probably mean just cursor

Answer (score 0):

The current best solution I found is to use `cursor.rowcount` after an `execute()`. This will be  > 0 if the `execute()` command returns a value otherwise it will be 0.

Comment: `cursor.rowcount` doesn't work for "SELECT ... INTO ..." so I won't recommend using this code for general purposes.